# КАК РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ СЧИТЫВАНИЕ 16-ричных целых чисел на СИ?

Tags: c, hex

Всем привет! У меня проблема: есть задание "на вход подается строка, содержащая целые числа в десятичной или шестнадцатеричной записи, разделенные пробельными символами, завершающаяся символом LF." (LF-enter)
Я реализовал для десятичных. Как сделать так, чтобы программа "понимала", какое число перед ней: HEX, или DEC? Понимаю, что вопрос максимально может быть тупым, но я уже на многих страницах побывал, а решения так и не нашел. Пожалуйста, помогите... Вот код на СИ (я вставил сам код, который уже внутри main, если что):

```
int *a = NULL, i = 0, d = 0, b = 0, elem;
char c;
do {
    scanf("%d", &elem);
    a = (int*)realloc(a, (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
    a[i] = elem;
    if (a[i] == (i * (i + 1)/2 + 1)) ++d;
    else ++b;
    i++;
    c = getchar();
    if (c=='\n')
        break;
} while (c == ' ');
if (d > 0 && b == 0) printf("ALL\n");
else if (d > 0 && b > 0) printf("SOME\n");
else if (d == 0 && b > 0) printf("NONE\n");
free(a);
return 0;
```

Comment: В общем случае никак. Так как 111 может быть и десятичным и шестнадцатеричным. Стандартно шестнадцатеричные числа обозначаются с префиксом, например так: 0x111

Comment: http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/isxdigit

Comment: Ну, по заданию там HEX и вводится через 0х, но как запустить проверку? Потому что в моем случае когда я начинаю такое число вводить он просто ноль записывает и все. А реализовывать через strtol, делая все строковыми у меня не вышло тк он просто каждый символ как отдельный элемент массива вписывает

Comment: Гляньте на [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) - при наличии префикса она сама понимает, как переводить... Для него - читайте ввод как строки.

Comment: "Ну, по заданию там HEX и вводится через 0х,..." - почему это не указано в тексте вопроса? И что это за "ALL", "SOME", "NONE" в коде? К чему они там?

Comment: "ALL", "SOME", "NONE" Это просто сообщение при результате программы. Это не нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаем числа разделенные пробелами. Строка начинается с цифры и заканчивается цифрой. Числа разделены 1 пробелом.

```
char s[256], *p;
int c;
int c;

    p = s;
    printf("input char: ");
    c = getchar();
    *p++ = c;
    while (c != '\n') {

        c = getchar();
        if (c ==' ' || c=='\n' ) {
            *p = '\0'; /* add null terminator */
            if (s[0] == '0' && s[1] == 'x') {
                printf("%ld\n", strtol(s, NULL, 16));
            }
            else {
                printf("%ld\n", strtol(s, NULL, 10));
            }

            p = s;
        }
        else {
            *p++ = c;
        }

    }
```